# fast intersection-test for great circle arcs (intersecion of geodesics on the sphere)

Tags: computational-geometry

I have the following problem:
let $(a_1,b_1)$ and ($a_2,b_2)$ be to geodesic lines on the sphere, i.e. great circle arcs.
I need to determine, if the two arcs intersect.

I already have a working solution namely: [this blog post](https://blog.mbedded.ninja/mathematics/geometry/spherical-geometry/finding-the-intersection-of-two-arcs-that-lie-on-a-sphere/).

The idea is the following: Calculate the two intersection points of the great circles and after that check if one of them lies on both arcs. Testing if an intersection point lies on an arc is done by using some angle calculations using trigonmetric functions.

In my application the trigonometric functions make the runtime very slow, since I have a lot of intersection tests. Hence I'm trying to find/develope an intersection test that does not need any trigonometry.

Another noteworthy thread would be the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668041/intersections-between-geodesics-shortest-distance-paths-on-the-surface-of-a-sp , but I think that the procedure does not work correctly in every case. For the following image the test would be true in my opinion (and  my implementation), but the arcs do not intersect.

[image]

Thus my questions would be:

1. Can we somehow substitute the trigonometiric calculations in the first idea?
2. Can we fix the second idea?
3. Has anybody a completely differnt approach that may work?